# Is there a way to create smth like a Scenario Outline in Gherkin that is executed for multiple values without restarting the Scenario?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, specflow, gherkin

I am a test designer and I am creating .feature files.
We are using Visual Studio + Specflow, the code is written in C#.

I have a following test case:

```
Background:
   Given something
   And something
   And something

Scenario: Scenario name
   When I set the 'X' value' in the Y field
   Then The 'X' value is displayed in 'Somewhere'
```

My problem is:
I need to check 20 values.
But if I use Scenario Outline with Examples, then it will be run from the start for each 'X' value I use, all Givens will be executed everytime.

This will take long while the test is quite simple and running the When+Then combination for each value after the background is run could be enough for the test purpose.

Is there a way to check multiple values in Gherkin without using the Scenario Outlines, having a possibility to just run a When and Then combination multiple times to check each value?

Appreciate any help with this matter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a datatable as input, and implement your step in such a way that it parses the datatable. You can then perform assertions on each table element.
[SpecFlow DataTables Documentation](http://specflow.org/documentation/SpecFlow-Assist-Helpers/)

```
Given I test the following outcomes
| value | field  | display_location |
| X     |   Y1   | Somewhere        |
| y     |   Y2   | Somewhere Els    |
```

By having an instance variable to hold the test values, you can perform actions and verifications in other steps on the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You have two steps - one to set some value to the field, and another to check if some field has given value:

```
[When(@"I set the '(.*)' value in the (.*) field")]
public void WhenISetTheValueInTheField(string value, string field)
{
   // ...
}

[Then(@"The '(.*)' value is displayed in (.*) field")]
public void ThenTheValueIsDisplayedInField(string value, string field)
{
    // ...
}
```

With Specflow you can call steps from [Step Definitions](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions). So basically you need a high-level step which will explain your high-level intent - verification that all given input values are displayed correctly. To pass values and verification data you can use a table:

```
Then all input values are displayed correctly:
| InputValue | InputField | DisplayedValue | DisplayField  |
| X          | Y          | X              | Somewhere     |
| Z          | Y          | Z              | SomewhereElse |
```

And inside this step, you can call steps which you already have for each set of data:

```
[Then(@"all input values are displayed correctly:")]
public void ThenAllInputValuesAreDisplayedCorrectly(Table table)
{
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var inputValue = row["InputValue"];
        var inputField = row["InputField"];
        When($"I set the '{inputValue}' value in the {inputField} field");

        var displayedValue = row["DisplayedValue"];
        var displayField = row["DisplayField"];
        Then($"The '{displayedValue}' value is displayed in {displayField} field");
    }
}
```

The Nice thing here is that beside high-level step, you will see each step with its parameters in the output.